# Haferschleim vs Haferbrei

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I said to my friend: "Ich esse morgens `Haferbrei`". He asked, whether I mean `Haferschleim`.

Is there any difference? Do these words have the same meaning or not?

---

What about other dishes, like `Buchweizenbrei`, `Reisbrei` or `Grießbrei`. Can they also be `-schleim`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically all cereal dishes come in four major variants:

> [Grütze](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCtze) - [Brei](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brei) - Schleim - [Suppe](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppe)

The difference is the consistency, and size of the grain. *"Grütze"* is made of larger grains and has a lower content of water/milk, softness and liquid content increases over *"Brei"* to *"Schleim"* and *"Suppe"*.

By adding the cereal name as a compound noun to the preparation we then will have such dishes like *"Haferbrei"*, *"Reisschleim"*, *"Maissuppe"*.

Comment: nice :) short but very interesting

Comment: +1 Muahaha, das wusste ich echt nicht. Die vier Aggregatzustände von Zeugs: Grütze-Brei-Schleim-Suppe. Das ist genial.

Comment: Thank you. It is clear now. But I also found in the dictonary `Grützbrei`. That is something that I don't understand.

Comment: @640miles: never heard of *"Grützbrei"* myself but I would say it is somewhere in between *Grütze* and *Brei*.

Comment: Schleim (engl. slime) is disgusting as food, Brei is a common kind of food.

Answer (score 2):

`Haferschleim` or `Hafersuppe` is the more diluted version of `Haferbrei`

The other mentioned descriptions can be found e.g. here

[Fasten](http://www.daskochrezept.de/fasten-fit-in-einer-fastenwoche/)

> 1. Schleimfasten: Hier gibt es ausschließlich leichten Reis-, Hafer-, Gerste- oder Buchweizenschleim. Der weiche Brei aus Wasser und
>      Getreide schont die Schleimhäute im Verdauungstrakt und sorgt dafür,
>      dass sie wieder gesund funktionieren. Die Kur eignet sich deshalb vor
>      allem für alle, die Magen- und Darmbeschwerden haben. Ausgiebig
>      Wassertrinken gehört selbstverständlich auch zu dieser Fastenkur.